# Use site's jQuery from content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script for my chrome extension which through the manifest is only executed on my target site. The target site uses jQuery so it is available.

But in my content script it isn't available.
I cant see everything else in the page just fine.
I could of course load jQuery for the extension separately but that seems a it wasteful. Is there a way to access it?

The content script section in my manifest looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*/relevant-path*"],
    "js": ["extension.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
]
```

In extension.js I add a load event handler like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

And in init I try to use jQuery which fails.

Comment: To access the page context you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Ah thanks that's it. If you give it as an answer I can accept that one and close the question.